# images are not loaded in the browser

Tags: firebase, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

**The issue :**

I created a SSR website using nuxt3 and used NuxtImage for optimizing the images.
It works well out of the box in dev mode, locally.

I deployed it to firebase functions + hosting using this firebase.json configuration :

```
{
  "functions": { "source": ".output/server", "runtime": "nodejs18" },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "my-website",
      "public": ".output/public",
      "cleanUrls": true,
      "rewrites": [
        { "source": "**", "function": "server" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But when accessing my site via the firebase url, the images are not loaded in the browser. In the network section, I can see 404 errors for the images.
And when entering manually the urls called like :

```
https://my-website.web.app/_ipx/_/img/404.jpg
```

returns the following message :

```
IPX Error: Error: File not found (/public/img/404.jpg)
```

**What I have tried :**

- Maybe the public folder was the problem so I used this script https://gist.github.com/mbleigh/9c8680cf319ace2f506f57380da66e7d
  to see if there was a public server on my hosting, there is not. I tried adding this, no luck.

  ```
        { "source": "/public", "destination": "/" },
  ```
- I also tried to put the public folder inside the .output/server but still the same error

I am very new to firebase functions and hosting so maybe there something I didn't understand ?
Anyway, thank you for reading

Comment: This question gets asked every hour here and all over the internet, seemingly, and the problem is always the same: your pathname is wrong.